# How do i see my records stored in the ethereum blockchain

Tags: solidity, truffle

So I have a smart contract, in my code, I have an array and i am pushing to it using a particular method call addToUser, from the code below
`Contract Example{
string[] users;
function addToUser(_user) public {
users.push(_user);
}
}`
from my understanding when I call the addToUser method above and I push records to it. **users** is stored in the contract storage(which I am thinking of, as a database). my confusion is, how do I see all the users. like how do I access the database to see all the records and what happens when I redeploy the contract?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare `string[] public users;`
2. Add `function getNumOfUsers() public view returns (uint256) {return users.length;}`
3. In your Truffle test, do something like this inside an `async` function:

```
const numOfUsers = await myContract.getNumOfUsers();
for (let i = 0; i < numOfUsers; i++)
    console.log(await myContract.users(i));
```

Comment: is there any other way i can do this? given that my contract is already deployed

Comment: @Alcantara: There are several ways. You haven't posted a single piece of code explaining what you want to do with that information, so I suggested one option. You also haven't specified why you are looking for other ways. Note that we're not here to guess what your goal here, so please explain it **in your question** in an explicit manner that would leave no room for guessing!

Comment: my question is not really a code issue, my code works. what I want is for example in my nodejs project, I have a database where I save everything to,  and I can access this database. my confusion is how do I check the record stored in my deployed contract. using a tool or something. thanks for your help

Comment: @Alcantara: Just as I showed you!